# Parse number from an image pytesseract

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am trying to parse a number from an image. Here's an example of the images
[image]

I tried first to extract all the text to have a look at the final result but the code didn't recognize the desired number
This is my try

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import fitz, pytesseract, os, re
import cv2


def readNumber(img):
    img = cv2.imread(img)
    gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gry)
    return txt
```

I am trying to parse the number after the slash in the second line. Here the expected is `502630`

Here's another sample picture that Ahx's code failed to parse the number from it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the [image processing](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#image-processing) part.

You could apply [adaptive thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html).

For example:

[image]

Now, you want `22 / 502630`, so you need to check whether `/` is in the current line, then if the line contains the '/' character, then take the right part.

```py
for line in text.split('\n'):
    if '/' in line:
        line = line.split('/')[1].split(' ')[0]
        print(line)
```

The result will be:

```
502630
```

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

bgr_image = cv2.imread("C8EE6.png")
scaled_image = cv2.resize(bgr_image, (0, 0), fx=3, fy=3)
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(scaled_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_image, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 61, 93)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, config="psm 6")

for line in text.split('\n'):
    if '/' in line:
        line = line.split('/')[1].split(' ')[0]
        print(line)
```

For the second image, if we apply the previous solution, the result will be:

[image]

We need different parameters for this solution since the output is not a clear image. We need to change the constant `C` and the `block size`

From the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html):

> The blockSize determines the size of the neighborhood area and C is a constant that is subtracted from the mean or weighted sum of the neighborhood pixels.

If we set `blockSize`=13 and `C`=2, the output image will be:

[image]

If you compare the 2-images, the latter will be more readable than the previous image. Now if you read it:

```
502630
```

Updated Code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

bgr_image = cv2.imread("UVetb.png")
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_image, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 13, 2)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, config="psm 6")

for line in text.split('\n'):
    if '/' in line:
        line = line.split('/')[1].split(' ')[0]
        print(line)
```

Will the updated code work on every image?

Can't guarantee, since each image requires a different block sizes and C parameters for getting the desired result.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you. I have edited the question and added another similar image but the code failed to parse the number from it. Can you have a look at it, please?

Comment: Sure, you can check the updated code